# Load json date format from MySQL table into PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, datetime

At University here we have some mysql table structures that has been created by a previous coder/guy. The structure itself is clean and perfect. We use the data from MySQL in order to login into the system. the login system which is in PHP works fine with $username and $password with sessions.

Problem:

We have table for each of us (users) with a expire date. The date which we need everytime swap our security cards. However, i would like to fetch/echo this expire date table and insert into everyones profile.php as soon they login.
The problem here is that it looks like the previous coder has used json.

Example:

table structure: username, password, expdate

Only the table expdate is coded in json (i think), because it has something like: 1544301180 or NULL -> which NULL indicates UNLIMITED and 1544301180 some kind of date. This date is at the moment non-human readable.

How can I implement it?

I will show you the complete php content:

INDEX.PHP (where people do the login)

```html
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>PHP Login Session Example</h1>
<div id="login">
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

LOGIN.PHP (the config and connection to mysql db)

```html
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "changed", "changed");
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("unibebio", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

SESSION.PHP (user session checker)

```html
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "changed", "changed");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("unibebio", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from users where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];

if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

All this works fine, till we are landing in PROFILE.PHP, which we need to show human readable expiration date format. But i have no clue how to do it and or implement it:

```html
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>UNIBE BIOCHEMIE</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it works and it echo's the username from the table of that specific user.

But how can I do the same for the expiration date that is (I think) json encoded?

As I said, the table structure is: username, password, expdate

Comment: i wouldn't say your structure is clean and perfect when you're injecting raw POST data into your SQL. Have a read on on SQL injection:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: thanks for your reply and help. But how does this help me to read the encoded json table expdate into human readable code? If i would know the expire date of all users i would rewrite all the code :). Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: use json_decode() if you'd like to convert json to raw data. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: ok. Thanks. So first i load the table "expdate" and after that the system decodes on the fly the content from the table to show the correct value/date? Does it works like that? Sorry for my nooby questions. I will try to read into json and to write the correct code. If successfull i will post it here, maybe someone one day needs it :)